# Getting Error: Content is not allowed in prolog in Android Studio

Tags: android

When i try to build my 1st app "Hello World" in Android Studio, i face this error message. I attach the screenshot also. Anyone having idea how to solve this. [image]

> C:\Users\WINDOWS\AndroidStudioProjects\app\src\main\res\values\colors.xml:1:1:
>   Error: Content is not allowed in prolog.

Comment: Post your colors.xml

Comment: Show your XML file where error occurs so we can help you out